# Angularjs UI collapse in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to embed some collapsible panels in a ngRepeat.
This is what I have:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="element in elements">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  {{element.name}}
  <button value="Collapse" ng-click="element.isCollapsed != element.isCollapsed"></button>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body" collapse="element.isCollapsed">
  Content
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I click on the button, the collapse doesn't work.

From the documentation I understand that the repeater creates a scope for every `element`.

And the attribute `collapse` of the panel-body should get the same scope, right?

It seems that the `scope.$watch` in the `collapse` directive is not working properly.

Comment: Please create a fiddle for the same. Please explain ng-click="element.isCollapsed != element.isCollapsed" You checking on the same element in the click event

Comment: Hi V31, thanks for your comment. I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nZ9Nx/7/ and corrected the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nZ9Nx/9/

I have created the app and injected ui-bootstrap in it to have the collapse working.

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: whats special about ui-bootstrap?

Comment: Its a library which defines directives for the bootstrap javascript components which are available. This helps in having the javacscript Components (outside angular scope) to be inside the angular scope.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. It works quite good! It's exactly what I need. Basically you used the classic ng-hide/ng-show bypassing the "collapse" directive, am I right? I was so focused in my solution and I wasn't able to see the easiest one. Thanks! It would be anyway interessant to understand why the `collapse` doesn't work...

Comment: @Enrico - hit the same problem now. I THINK it is to do with the way angular processes templates and the way the bootstrap collapse plugin works. Basically, I THINK by the time the bootstrap javascript (required for collapse plugin) kicks in, the ng-repeat stuff has not yet happened, so in effect boostrap JS never get's a chance to do it's magic.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is

```
<div class="panel-heading" toggle target="collapseOne">
```

It's hardcoded in the example. Replace with...

```
<div class="panel-heading" toggle target="collapse{{ $index + 1 }}">
```

Also update this tag

```
<div id="collapse{{ $index + 1 }}" toggleable active-class="in" exclusion-group="accordion1" default="active" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Here is a full example

```
<div ng-repeat="item in awesomeThings">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" toggle target="collapse{{ $index + 1 }}">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                {{ item }}
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{ $index + 1 }}" toggleable active-class="in" exclusion-group="accordion1" default="active" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey what if the collapsed panel is not in ng-repeat scope then how do you trigger collapse